# How do I manage versions with Git

Tags: git

I am an individual developer and never worked in a company. I have just finished a new product and pushed it to the `master` branch as version 1 with:

```
git add .
git commit -m "v1.0.0 final"
git push origin master
```

Now I want to start the work on the 2nd version of the product where I will have some additions and enhancements. Should I create a new branch for this? As far as I understood, branches are for experimental enhancements, and not for version control? If I keep pushing to `master`, will I then be able to download the initial version 1 if needed?

Comment: Tags are usually used to mark released versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Manage each version of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400460/git-manage-each-version-of-my-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `master` branch should reflect what is production-ready, and you should only ever push to it when you are happy that your code is ready for a new release to the public. You should have a 'primary' branch called `develop` (which is your main development branch), and you should branch `feature` branches off of that.

For example, you have your code in `develop`, and want two new independent features. You branch `feature/1` and `feature/2` off of `develop`, and merge each one back to `develop` when you are happy that the respective features are complete. `develop` is deployed out to your testing sites. After testing your changes are sound on `develop`, you can push `develop` to `master`, which should only be done when you're ready to release your code to the public.

When the code reaches `master`, you can [**tag the release**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) with a version number. You can always roll back the version number on `master` if necessary.

This is called **[Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)**, and is demonstrated in the following image:

[image: Git Flow]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and the blog author has nailed it :)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create a new branch for this?

Different people use different strategies. A common plan is to create a branch from master for each version when you're getting ready to release, and use the master branch to contain current development. That way, if you need to release a bug fix or other patch to a given version, you can do it in the branch for that version, possibly also merging the fix back into master. Use tags to identify the specific commit for each release.